# ! defined (BASEPATH) not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I tried putting

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

on the top of my controller, but still it is directly accessible.

Answer (score 4):

All requests should go through `index.php`, where the `BASEPATH` gets defined. It prevents them from `http://example.com/application/models/model.php` via the URL and directly accessing the model, library, etc. It is a security measure.

if you see in `index.php` file there is line which defines the `basepath`

```
// Path to the system folder
define('BASEPATH', str_replace('\\', '/', $system_path));
```

**For Example**

if you trying access like `example.com/application/controllers/Home.php` then you get error `No direct script access allowed`